# One binary halts at breakpoint, the other doesn't - no breakpoint is defined

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m, stm32f4, openocd

I'm trying to run a Rust Hello World on my STM32F401xB. I have a working C program for comparison (different functionality, but it verifies the flashing toolchain) and use the same openocd commands to flash both programs onto the controller.

When I flash the C program, I get:

```
...
** Verified OK **
adapter speed: 2002 kHz
```

When I flash the Rust program, I get the following:

```
...
** Verified OK **
adapter speed: 2002 kHz
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x21000000 pc: 0x08002f42 msp: 0x2000ffa0
```

note the two extra lines. When I connect using `gdb` and `continue`, I get the `Hello, World!` printout through semihosting, so the program does in principle execute fine - it just pauses before main even though I have not set a breakpoint. My procedure for both binaries is the same. What could be going on? Why are the two binaries behaving differently?

---

- I used `svd2rust` to create a `stm32f40x` crate from the official `stm32f401.svd`
- I used the `cortex-m-quickstart` and basically the `hello.rs` example - configuring `memory.x` and adding the dependency to `stm32f40x` of course
- there are no special configurations (that I would have identified) in my project, and the same behavior happens for debug and release builds.

Comment: Show the disassembly of the code at the breakpoint.  It is possible that the code contains a direct beakpoint instruction in a conditional of the form `if debugger attached then break`  Also [this](https://michaelwoerister.github.io/2013/09/27/what-you-call-the-present.html) may be relevant - specifically the part about changing the start-on-startup symbol from `main` to `helloworld::main`

Comment: The `cortex-m-quickstart` uses `#![no_main]` and `entry!(func);` to define the entry function into the binary, so I don't think the problem is with a symbol name. But I'm sure you're right that I'll see a breakpoint in the disassembly; probably from semihosting as Turbo J wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the Hello, World! printout through semihosting

Check the semihosting documentation. Last time I checked, semihosting works using breakpoints on several ARM targets.

Your C program probably does not use semihosting at all, so no breakpoints are used.

Comment: That must have been it. After removing semihosting, the message disappears! Lucky this detail appeared in the question...